# Transaction Isolation (No Concurrent read to same data)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I need your help with one problem. Currently I’ve a situation wherein I’ve a bunch of users in my db and I’ve to assign **lastName** to these users (only once).
If **last_name** column is null than I’ll pull first such record from the database and assign it **last_name** (update user record) and update in to the database.
To get first such record I am using `findFirstByLastNameIsNull()` [**Spring data repository**] method in **UserDetailsService.java**. I am using Insomnia (Rest Client) to hit the Rest API. Problem is that If I put a debugger @ line 37 (to simulate the condition that first transaction has not been completed yet on first rest call, I get the result id = 4, which is ok..)  and when I hit API second time I get the same result (id = 4 from db).

After I halted on line 37 for first request, I was expecting (id = 5) will be returned on second call as first request/transaction isn’t completed. But every time it’s returning (id = 4). I’ve also tried by setting **Isolation level** to **Serialization** but same behaviour :(

Idea is in a test web(concurrent) we’ve to assign last_name only once. How we can take care such scenario to avoid race condition ?

```
    package com.test.tx.management.service;

import com.test.tx.management.model.UserDetails;
import com.test.tx.management.repository.UserDetailsRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Isolation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public class UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;

    public UserDetails findFirstByLastNameIsNull() {
//        Optional<UserDetails> optionalUserDetails = userDetailsRepository.findFirstByLastNameEndingWith("ena");
        Optional<UserDetails> optionalUserDetails = userDetailsRepository.findFirstByLastNameIsNull();

        if (!optionalUserDetails.isPresent()) {
            return null;
        } else if (optionalUserDetails.get().getId() == 4) {
            UserDetails userDetails = optionalUserDetails.get();
            userDetails.setLastName("UserLastName 4");
            userDetailsRepository.save(userDetails);
            System.out.println("Halting when userid = 4, For First request...");
        }
        // Logic to update last_name here...
        return optionalUserDetails.get();
    }


    public void saveUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails) {
        userDetailsRepository.save(userDetails);
    }

    public UserDetails findUserDetailsById(Integer userId) {
        Optional<UserDetails> userDetailsOptional = userDetailsRepository.findById(userId);
        if (!userDetailsOptional.isPresent()) {
            return null;
        }
        return userDetailsOptional.get();
    }

    public int countUnAssignedLastName() {
        return userDetailsRepository.countByLastNameIsNull();
    }
}
```

####################

```
package com.test.tx.management.repository;

import com.test.tx.management.model.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDetails, Integer> {
    //    Optional<UserDetails> findFirstByLastNameEndingWith(String startsWith);
    Optional<UserDetails> findFirstByLastNameIsNull();

    int countByLastNameIsNull();
}
```

[image]

Comment: And you expect an answer while posting unreadable screenshots? Please add some code as code not as images. One thing which is visible is a wrong usage of optional in your code. But as stated please add code as code not as images as that is unreadable.

Comment: Also you are doing a lookup in a transaction, however your WHOLE business usecase should be transactional. Currently nothing is getting locked and even if it would it would be released again.

Comment: There is no service method obtaining and updating the record, so not sure how you are updating things (which should be done in a single transactional method in the first place). You are probably doing a query, update in your controller and call save on the service again (from the controller. Which is basically wrong as it should be 1 single service method. Then using the proper locking modes (probably pessimistic here) and/or serialization will solve it. Or rewrite the whole solution to update directly instead of loading/updating.

Comment: I think you are confusing isolation level with concurency.  Isolation level applies to uncommitted changes. Since you are not doing any changes here, dirty check is not done by transactions and each read may return same result. Try making the row dirty by making change you are looking for.

Comment: Tired to update as per the suggestion, but still the same behaviour :( I am not very smart in Transactions; but requirement is that once We get user whose information is being updated by one Transaction, it should not be updated by another concurrent transactions.

Comment: Can anyone please address this issue ?